# zf1: retrieving subforms

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form that contains 5 sub-forms of the class A, and another sub-form of the class B.

I want to show in the view first the sub-forms of the class A but I don't know how to retrieve only them.

Should i create another sub-form that contains the 5 sub-forms of the class A?
Is there any way to get the sub-form based on a pattern?

I'm instanting the forms in the controller like this:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
   {
       $form = new ContractLink_Form_ContractOMFOverrideAppendix();
       $form->setElementsBelongTo('override' . $i);
       if(isset($overrides[$i])) {
           $form->populate($overrides[$i]);
       }

       $formSuper->addSubForm($form, 'OMFOverrideAppendixForm' . $i);
   }
```

I'm using zf1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on IRC,

You could use the [instanceof PHP operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) to check the class of the subform.

```
$subForms = $form->getSubForms();
foreach ( $subForms as $subForm ) {
    if ($subForm instanceof A) {
        // stuff to do for 'A' type of subform
    }
}
```